# Create a decorator that has access to both the arguments and function

Tags: python, function, methods, arguments, decorator

I am modifying the following decorator class. Is it possible to get the arguments for `func` as well as having access to the function?

```
def arg(*args, **kwargs):
    def _decorator(func):
        # check for funcs args

        func.do_something(args, kwargs)
        return func
    return _decorator
```

As it seems that everything i have tried, means that you only get access to one or the other.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do with the arguments?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I just want to get one of the value of one of the kwargs of the function and compare it to a value passed into the decorator.

Comment: so you you would pass a keyword argument to decorator at time of definition of the function and you want to test the value passed to that same keyword argument when the function is called at runtime right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by accessing the arguments and the function. I am guessing you mean the arguments passed to the function.

For your usecase, for decorators that take arguments, you need another wrapper function , that would do the testing of kwargs against the kwargs passed to the function at runtime.

Example -

```
>>> def arg(*args, **kwargs):
...     def _decorator(func):
...         def _wrapper(*args1, **kwargs1):
...             # check for funcs args
...             for k,v in kwargs.items():
...                 print("For key - ",k,v == kwargs1.get(k))
...             func(*args1, **kwargs1)
...         return _wrapper
...     return _decorator
...
>>>
>>> @arg(l = 1)
... def b(l):
...     print("In B", l)
...
>>> b(l=1)
For key -  l True
In B 1
>>> b(l=2)
For key -  l False
In B 2
```

---

**EDIT:** This is for decorators without arguments.

The outer function receives the function as argument, and the inner function receives the arguments to the function.

A very simple example -

```
>>> def a(func):
...     def x(*args, **kwargs):
...             print(args, kwargs)
...             func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return x
...
>>> @a
... def b(y):
...     print("In b", y)
...
>>> b("Hello")
('Hello',) {}
In b Hello
```

---

Comment: In your example if @a had arguments such as @a('hello2') how would you access both the "hello" and "hello2"?

Comment: I have updated the answer for decorators with arguments.

Comment: Ah i see the second bit now, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Oh this only works for one @arg(l =1) decorator, what happens if i want to add a couple that get ran? Such as @arg(l =1) @arg(o=2) ect?

Comment: They should work as well. This would work any amount of arguments in decorator. Are you getting any error?